# Change multiple answer to one

Tags: spss, qualtrics

I made the mistake of leaving the "*What is your gender*" question as a multiple choice in Qualtrics instead of a "pick one".

I exported the data to SPSS and this makes me unable to do correlations etc.
Is there an easy way to fit the answers given back into one variable, in which 1=male 2=female 3=other?

Instead of 3 different variables with
1 Male
1 Female
1 Other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say your variables are `male`, `female`, `other`, you can use this:

```
if male=1 sex=1. 
if female=1 sex=2. 
if other=1 sex=3.
value labels sex
   1  'male'
   2  'female'   
   3  'other'.
```

Now you'll have to decide what happens if respondents selected more than one possible answer. The simplest solution could be:

```
if sum(male, female, other)>1 sex=$sysmis.
```

On the other hand, if you want to lose as little data as possible, you could go this way for example:

```
if male=1 and other=1 sex=1.
if female=1 and other=1 sex=2.
if male=1 and female=1 sex=$sysmis.
```

Comment: I have checked and no respondent has selected more than one sex. Right now I have three different lines of value with male=1 female=1 other=1. I would like to change this into one line with male=1 female=2 other=3

Comment: you mean you have three variables named `male`, `female`, `other` right? I edited the code above accordingly. If there are no cases of choosing more than one answer that the first code block should do all the work (note I added the value labels).